# Generating different experimental data sets

Tags: python, machine-learning

I want to generate 5 experimental data sets for my dataset (heart.csv).
https://www.kaggle.com/ronitf/heart-disease-uci. Then for each experimental data set, I conduct 5 fold cross-validation.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have read all the data into a dataframe called `df`, then try this:

```
import numpy as np

#Shuffle data
df_shuffled_1 = df.sample(frac=1)
df_shuffled_2 = df_shuffled_1.sample(frac=1)
...
```

Comment: You can just shuffle the dataframe before splitting it, using sample(). Have edited the answer above.

Comment: Sorry, small misunderstanding. In case you do not want to split it, then no need for np.array_split(). You can just keep calling the df.sample() function 10 times which will shuffle the dataset. I would suggest using a for loop.

Comment: I just edited the answer again.